# Need Help Securing Router and Reduce Packet Loss

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am just an average home user and not a networking expert. I can't get any support from ISP during the lockdown so I am posting here.

My internet keeps disconnecting ocassionally. I used a troubleshooting tip to ping my router to see its status.

I used terminal app on my Mac which is connected via WIFI and pinged 192.168.100.1 which is my router's IP address and it is less than 12 feet away from me.

Ping replies would be slower and in between, they will drop

```
64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=147 ttl=64 time=81.393 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=148 ttl=64 time=69.034 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 149
64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=150 ttl=64 time=192.465 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 152
Request timeout for icmp_seq 153
Request timeout for icmp_seq 154
Request timeout for icmp_seq 155
Request timeout for icmp_seq 156
Request timeout for icmp_seq 157
```

I logged in to my router which is Huawei HG8245A. In the user log I noticed this:

```
2020-03-25 12:55:43 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(92.114.183.119),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:guest
2020-03-25 12:55:44 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(92.114.183.119),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:root
2020-03-25 12:55:44 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(92.114.183.119),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:Administrator
2020-03-25 12:55:44 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(92.114.183.119),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:root
2020-03-25 12:55:45 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(92.114.183.119),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:root
2020-03-25 12:55:45 [Error][Alarm-Log] AlarmID:104032,AlarmLevel:Error,Administrator exceeded maximum number of attempted logins.Terminal:CLI
2020-03-25 13:00:45 [Error][Alarm-Log] AlarmID:104519,AlarmLevel:Error,[CLI]unlocked!
2020-03-25 13:02:31 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:WEB(192.168.100.12),Result:Success,Type:Login,Username:telecomadmin
2020-03-25 13:08:33 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:WEB(192.168.100.12),Result:Success,Type:Logout,Username:telecomadmin
2020-03-25 13:09:23 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(49.88.77.4),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:root
2020-03-25 13:15:32 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(113.23.83.207),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:root
2020-03-25 13:15:32 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(113.23.83.207),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:root
2020-03-25 13:15:33 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(113.23.83.207),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:root
2020-03-25 13:15:33 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(113.23.83.207),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:admin1
2020-03-25 13:15:33 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:CLI(113.23.83.207),Result:Fail,Type:Login,Username:service
2020-03-25 13:15:33 [Error][Alarm-Log] AlarmID:104032,AlarmLevel:Error,Administrator exceeded maximum number of attempted logins.Terminal:CLI
2020-03-25 13:20:33 [Error][Alarm-Log] AlarmID:104519,AlarmLevel:Error,[CLI]unlocked!
2020-03-25 13:20:53 [Critical][Config-Log] Terminal:WEB(192.168.100.12),Result:Success,Type:Login,Username:telecomadmin
```

To me, it seems like many of these are IP addresses from around the world trying to login to my router.

Now, I know there are ways to protect my router somewhere in the settings. But I am not sure where those options are and I am afraid that I might mess it up and will be left without internet during lockdown.

Can someone please tell me how to block these or if there is a tutorial somewhere that I can use?

Thank you so much, 
Stay safe, stayathome

Comment: You can't block those attempts. Be thankful they have all failed.

Comment: Look for and disable remote (internet) access options. Some routers allow internet facing logins and have configuration options for it. Make sure that any options you change are specific to the Internet/WAN side and not the local/LAN side as that would make if difficult to configure it at all.

Comment: You’re mixing two topics in one question: Your Wi-Fi problems and your router security problem. // Can you try with a wired connection?

Comment: @Mokubai thanks I was able to uncheck Allow WAN-side PCs to access ONT through Telnet. but it didnt stop those login attempts. 

DanielB I don't have access to a laptop or device with LAN port.

Comment: There is little evidence your router is not performing because if an external attack - and your symptoms are entirely consistent with WiFi issues - these could be environmental, hardware or firmware related. Try a cable to confirm the problem is WiFi, then download a WiFi scanner and start mapping out channels/usage cases.

Comment: Ask your ISP to change your IP address and see if the attacks persist. Also, are they DSL, Cable, or Fiber Optic?